# global variable in onclicklistner

Tags: java, android, onclick, global-variables, onclicklistener

I am a beginner in Android development and working on a project,
I am trying to access a global variable in onclick listner but i show an error.
Here is Global Class

```
    public class GlobalClass extends Application{

private String globalUrl;

public String getGlobalUrl() {
    return globalUrl;
}

public void setGlobalUrl(String globalUrl) {
    this.globalUrl = globalUrl;
}
    }
```

Here its my main activity class which shows error on getApplication(),
i want to use My global variables in activity class as well as simple class.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button Enter;
EditText textEdit;
TextView text;
String url;

private static String ur = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Calling Application class (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)

    textEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.postalText);
     text  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewme);
    Enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_Enter);



   Enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v){
          // Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,jsonParsingActivity.class);
           Intent launchActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this,jsonParsingActivity.class);
           startActivity(launchActivity);


           url = ur+ textEdit.getText().toString();
           ((GlobalClass) this.getApplication()).setGlobalUrl(url);
           System.out.println(url);
           Log.v(url, "extended url");

   }
   });

}
```

How to remove this error...
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: cannot resolve getApplication

Comment: Did you register your application class in your manifest?

Comment: I suppose this is bad pattern

Comment: @TheTanic i have registerd in manifest like this
  <application
        android:name="GlobalClass"

Comment: @scienticious You need do declare it with the full package path. If this doesn´t solve your problem, pls post your full error log

Comment: @TheTanicI have declare full package path but error is not resolved..
**these are the error of the error log

Error:(54, 35) error: cannot find symbol method getApplication()

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.**

Comment: Pls edit your question and post there your complete error log! And try the answer of oberflansch. This should be working

Comment: check out my solution below it's works fine if you call like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this lines to place the value in global class variables

replace your code

```
((GlobalClass) this.getApplication()).setGlobalUrl(url);
```

with the below code

```
GlobalClass temp=new GlobalClass();
temp.setGlobalUrl(url);
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants to do. You don´t create a new Object of an Application class...

Comment: This might work, but new instances of the application class should not be created. The Application represents the global Context of your App and there should not be more than one. It is confusing and can cause bugs on other places, e.g. when you try to use the url in an other place.

Comment: there will be no problem with that I was tested also.. it's working fine for me I accessed in other places also there is no issue..

Comment: **it is working**...
Thanks @saikrupa
I dont have reputation more than 15 so i cant vote up your question

Comment: kindly just accept my answer so that I will get the reputations @scienticious

Comment: @TheTanic this is the correct code what i want, my code is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
MainActivity.this.getApplication()
```

instead of

```
this.getApplication()
```

If you call `this` in your View.OnClickListener it referes to the View.OnClickListener.